# JQUERY function won't load

Tags: jquery, function, class, if-statement

Doing a huge project atm, and i've got a problem with a JQ function not loading.
I've been looking this over a bunch of times now an honestly.. I can't find mistake. I might be tunnelvisioning it or something because, something as basic as this should really not be troubling me.

http://jsfiddle.net/qwb4wrg6/

I've created a fiddle for the purpose of solving this.

Problem in short:
*Angle on the right, won't change classes*

```
$(function () {
$("click-nav1").click(function () {
    if ($("#MYFEED_ANGLE").hasClass("fa fa-angle-down")) {
        $("#MYFEED_ANGLE").removeClass("fa fa-angle-down").addClass("fa fa-angle-up");
    }
    else {
        $("#MYFEED_ANGLE").removeClass("fa fa-angle-up").addClass("fa fa-angle-down");
    }
});
});
$(function () {
$('.click-nav1 > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
$('.click-nav1 .js ul').hide();
$('.click-nav1 .js').click(function (e) {
    $('.click-nav1 .js ul').slideToggle(200);
    $('.clicker1').toggleClass('active');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.click-nav1').click(function () {
    if ($('.click-nav1 .js ul').is(':visible')) {
        $('.click-nav1 .js ul', this).slideUp();
        $('.clicker1').removeClass('active');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: The down-turned angle on the right side of the div.
One can see it, if looking closely, on the right side of the fiddle result.

Comment: Oh yeah. Stupid, huh!? Fixed it, but still having the issue.

Comment: is "$("click-nav1").click"  missing the "."  in the class reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hasClass("fa fa-angle-down")` is not valid.  "fa fa-angle-down" is two classes.

Additional errors:
`$("click-nav1")` is invalid.  click-nav1 is a class not a tag, and would need a . in front.
click-nav1 is the wrong element to place the event on, as you have other javascript that stops the propegation of the click from bubbling up to that element anyhow.  Change it to a click event on clicker1.

Fixed here:http://jsfiddle.net/qwb4wrg6/1/

Comment: Enlighten me. How is "fa fa-angle-down" two classes?

Comment: @RasmusHjorthLüdeking A space `" "` is used to separate multiple classes. When you are assigning a class like so `class="fa fa-angle-down"` it's given two classes the `fa` and the `fa-angle-down` class.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that tbh - guess i've never had to specify two classes before. Well seeing as "fa fa-angle-up" is, as i expect, coded into the css of font-awesome, is there any way to bypass this "space" issue, that you would know of?

Comment: @RasmusHjorthLüdeking Just do something like:`hasClass("fa-angle-down")`

Comment: Remove "fa" from the javascript checks, it always has the fa class, so checking for it and removing it only to add it back isn't necessary.  Also, the whole click event isn't needed at all as you are already placing the active class on the link, and you don't need another click event to add/remove classes from internal stuff.  You will however, need to change your CSS.

Comment: Here is the example with no additional javascript at all: http://jsfiddle.net/qwb4wrg6/2/

Comment: Just for futher information, if you needed to check for both classes (which you don't), it would be `if ($("#MYFEED_ANGLE").hasClass("fa") && $("#MYFEED_ANGLE").hasClass("fa-angle-down"))`

Comment: Additionally, if you wanted to keep the javascript version, you can simplify your code like so: http://jsfiddle.net/bnc5Lk7r/2/  (Using toggleClass to toggle two classes)

Comment: I'm so confused... It is perfectly valid jQuery to call `hasClass`, `addClass` and `removeClass` with two classes.  You can test it on this site--the body tag has two classes, call all three functions in the browser's console with both classes separated by a space in the string you pass in.

Comment: It's not valid to call hasClass with multiple classes, but it doesn't check to make sure that you don't send it multiple classes.  Technically, `<div id='test' class="a b">` and querying if `$('#test').hasClass('b a')` should return true as it has both class b and a, but it returns false because that method isn't designed to handle it being passed multiple classes.  addClass and removeClass does accept multiple classes.

Comment: See this for more details: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/